# A way to process a CTE once?

Tags: sql-server, cte, recursive

I have a view that has serious performance issues, because I am linking it to a CTE that uses another view, with the same table references.

```
WITH
  splits(ID, [NEW TEU])
  AS
    (SELECT s.[DTL ID] AS ID, s.[NEW TEU]
     FROM   [POTS].[vwSPLITCARGO] AS s)
     
SELECT *
FROM   [MISNT].[CARGO_MANIFEST_DETAIL_VIEW] AS cmd
       LEFT JOIN splits AS s ON s.ID = cmd.ID
```

The `vwSPLITCARGO` view, references the same `CARGO_MANIFEST_DETAIL_VIEW` table to get it's calculations.

**I know why it's slow**. It's because the `vwSPLITCARGO` view is reading all the data from the same `CARGO_MANIFEST_DETAIL_VIEW` view for every record already in the CTE. In fact, the `vwSPLITCARGO` is always returning the same small set of records (approx 4 or 6 records). I don't need it to get those records all the time. Once would be great!

Is there a way to make the CTE behave like a *temporary table*, in that it retrieves the records once, and not be processed over and over?

Something to tell the CTE: `CASE WHEN RunOnce = 0 THEN "do it" ELSE "don't do it" END`

Comment: If you want it to behave like a temp table, why not just use a temp table instead of a cte?

Comment: @AMtwo not that straight forward because the vwSPLITCARGO view could bring up other records, so in essence it's "temporary" only for the processing of the above view - at the time. If you know what I mean? It would be good to have a way to refresh/reinsert a table in SQL server automatically based on a view change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no query hint to spool or materialize a CTE.  So use a temp table, and optionally index the temp table.

```
SELECT s.[DTL ID] AS ID, s.[NEW TEU]
into #splits
FROM   [POTS].[vwSPLITCARGO] AS s;

WITH
  splits(ID, [NEW TEU])
  AS
    (select * from #splits)
     
SELECT *
FROM   [MISNT].[CARGO_MANIFEST_DETAIL_VIEW] AS cmd
       LEFT JOIN splits AS s ON s.ID = cmd.ID
```

Comment: I am lazy, but can all this be acceptable into a single view? I didn't think sql server views allowed to create temporary tables.

Comment: No.  Views can't use temp tables, but Table-Valued Functions can.  Or you might be able to make vwSPLITCARGO an indexed view.